# MVC4 Paging Nugget package workflow

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, pagination

I have implemented the MVC4 pagination library from nugget package. It works fine.

When there are thousands of records my application works fine with paging not when site load data increase around 10 lack, application remain slow.

See my code below.

```
private const int defaultPageSize = 10;     
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
        {
            int currentPageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value : 1;

            var items = db.GetAllEmployees(); // This will return all the records

            var result = items.Documents.ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, defaultPageSize);


            return View(result);
        }
```

How to solve this thing when site data load increase.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you always load all data, instead load only what you need, look at example. I used `context.MyTable`, because I don't know logic of your `GetAllEmployees()` method. Also you will not need pagination Nuget package.

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
    int currentPageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value : 1;

    var items = context.MyTable.Skip((currentPageIndex - 1) * defaultPageSize)
    .Take(defaultPageSize).ToList();

    return View(items);
}
```

Comment: GetAllEmployees() logic is just context.MyTable.ToList(). Another thing is then how to implement same paging instead of Nuget?

Comment: Instead ToPagedList you will use Skip and Take combination.

Comment: I agree but how to create paging control like this. any example?

Comment: What you mean about  paging control, what is it?

Comment: You question was - how to solve slow loading _when site data load increase_, not how to implement paging control. As you noticed, action's return value remains the same, consequently you can **try** to use your old paging control, but **it may not work**.  You should choose between reducing time of loading and creating custom paging control or remain all as it were at initial state, also you can try to tune existing control to new data extracting logic.

Comment: so finally i have to create my own pagination to reduce data load, Yes ?

Comment: Yes, you can create simple table, for example with two buttons: previous and next. On client side just you will store currentpage number and on nextbutton click load currentpage+1, previous: currentpage-1. Yes this table will be handmade and no so cute as initial control, but you can control data loading process and reduce it time. Also you can calculate on first time how many pages you will have (all rows/ defaultPageSize) and show them on client side - it is not very hadr to perform.